# There are no commands defined in the "setup:cron" namespace after upgrade to Magento 2.4.6-p3

Tags: module, extensions, cron, magento-cron, system.log

After upgrading to magento 2.4.6-p3 in system.log and cron.log it is generating same error daily i.e -

```
main.ERROR: There are no commands defined in the "setup:cron" namespace.
Did you mean one of these?
    setup
    setup:config
    setup:db
    setup:db-data
    setup:db-declaration
    setup:db-schema
    setup:di
    setup:performance
    setup:static-content
    setup:store-config
```

Can  anyone suggest any solution or the cause for the error in system.log and cron.log file

Comment: Can you try to remove cron first & then install it again? Because the setup:cron might be defined in the installed CRON.
bin/magento cron:remove
bin/magento cron:install

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.4.6-p3 there is no command with "setup:cron". check if any of your modules using this command.

Comment: Yes.  I have found one file crontab.xml with this code - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Magento/Cron/etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default"/>
</config> Is it causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can check the installed CRON because **setup:cron** was used in the CRON installation earlier.

So to verify the installed CRON, please use following command:

```
crontab -l
```

If the **cron:setup** exists for the installed CRON, please reinstall the CRON using the following commands:

```
bin/magento cron:remove 
bin/magento cron:install
```

Comment: Tried same but still the issue persists